# Create a review task on updates to the thread

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits

I love the way SO (and SE in general) focuses on `Questions` and `Answers` - trying to eliminate all "discussion" or "chat", even.
Often we are still seeing the "comments" being used inproperly.

To my understanding the main intention of a comment is to either point out that some part of the answer or question is "incorrect", or most importantly to give advice how to improve the answer or question.

So we want to the author to revise is contribution.
But what if he does?
Often the previous comment no longer matches. So the commenter should also revise (or remove) his commment.

To keep track of such updates there could be a TODO list created for the individual users with review tasks.

I'll try to outline the scenario:

1. UserA creates a new question
2. UserB adds a comment
3. UserA revises his question

Now, what should happen?

**A)** When UserB adds his comment in step **2** the author should be assigned a new review task.
Something like: "A new comment was added to your question XYZ".
He can do either of the following:

- select "clear the review task". my initial question still holds good. no need to revise it.
- go ahead and edit his question. this will automatically clear the review task.

**B)** When UserA revises his question in step **3** the commenter should be assigned a new review task.
Something like: "The initial question XYZ was revised after you had added a comment to it".
He can do either of the following:

- select "clear the review task". my comment still holds good. no need to revise it.
- go ahead and delete his comment. this will automatically clear the review task.

Once again: i see a clear benefit in updating and revising the individual contributions.
Thats the right way to improve the quality by at the same time avoiding any iterative discussion.

However, by following this practice there should be a way to easily keep track of the updates.
That's where automatic generation of "review tasks" for the individual users may help.

I think it can easily be implemented by evaluationg the "last modification date" of the various items (questions, answers, comments).

Comment: You can star a question when you comment if you want to stay updated.

Comment: Jon Skeet asked for something similar several years ago for votes. update: Found it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/210016

Answer (score 2):

> A) When UserB adds his comment in step 2 the author should be assigned a new review task.
>   Something like: "A new comment was added to your question XYZ".
>   He can do either of the following:
>
> - select "clear the review task". my initial question still holds good. no need to revise it.
> - go ahead and edit his question. this will automatically clear the review task.

There are two classes of users that will respond to this review task:

1. Those who listen to comments. Why is this needed **at all** for them? When someone adds a comment to a post, the post's author is notified. Right then they can decide to edit their question or not edit it. If they forget to act right away, they can go back later in their profile and check under `responses` to find the message.
2. Those who don't listen to comments. It does not matter if the review task can be ignored or not. If it can be ignored, they'll ignore it. If not, they'll just clear the task.

Either way, this feature does not provide any new benefit.

> B) When UserA revises his question in step 3 the commenter should be assigned a new review task. Something like: "The initial question XYZ was revised after you had added a comment to it". He can do either of the following:
>
> - select "clear the review task". my comment still holds good. no need to revise it.
> - go ahead and delete his comment. this will automatically clear the review task.

If users can ignore these tasks, then I guarantee you that soon everybody will just ignore them. You don't have yet the power to vote to close questions. So you don't get to vote in the reopen queue. This is the queue in which questions that have been closed and have been edited after being closed or on which someone has voted to reopen are put so that other members of the community can vote to reopen or leave closed. Once you get this privilege, you'll see a lot of:

1. Edits that just edit punctuation or things that have nothing to do with the reason the question was closed.
2. Edits that merely state that the close reason was wrong but without explaining why it was wrong. (Bonus points for questioning the intelligence of those who voted to close.)
3. Edits that fix one problem but don't fix other problems. For instance a question was too broad and opinion-based but now is just too broad.
4. Edits that introduce new problems while fixing others. For instance a question that was too broad now asks for an off-site resource.

It is bad enough that we get these edits in the reopen queue. After getting a bunch of "personal" review tasks based on these kinds of edits, most users will just ignore these "personal" review tasks.

And then there are comments that don't call for changes to the question. For instance, user A posts a question, user B points out a perceived flaw and user C corrects user B's misconception. Why on earth should user C then get a review task if the question is subsequently edited (which would be most likely *not* due to user C's comment)?

If the idea is to force users to address these "personal" review tasks, the most likely effect this will have is that people will stop commenting unless they feel that absolutely must. Already some people are extremely reluctant to leave a comment if they downvote or vote to close because a) revenge downvoting happens and b) even without the revenge downvotes some people just don't take comments (even as polite and factual as possible) the right way. With what you suggest, someone leaving a comment would not only expose themselves to these potential headaches but would *also* get review tasks when the question is edited.

What I *would* support is a feature request to make it so that when I look at my previous close votes in my profile, I can see which questions have been edited after I voted to close them.

Answer (score 1):

The review queues are for reviewing poor content and keeping the site clean, not for users to keep tabs on the content they interact with. You need to use the right tools for the job.

By posting a comment, the owner already receives an inbox notification that will lead them straight to the post. When fixed, they can post a comment to notify the other user that the problem's been fixed or just go on with their day. There's really no need for review tasks. That's hammering a nail with a sledgehammer.

If you really want to keep tabs without comments, star it. Then you'll know when changes have been made to it when you view your favorites tab.

Comment: 1) please note that in my proposal i'm not referring to the "review queues" that already exist. instead, i'm suggesting to introduce "personal" review tasks on a per user basis. 2) the favourites (star) is a good way to quickly see recent updates. however, it does not actively force users to act.